# Convert a RewriteRule from nginx to apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, rewrite

i want to convert a nginx rewriterule to a htaccess rewrite rule.

The nginx one is the following:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1 last;
```

I tried it with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1
```

... but i doesnt work correctly. (No Page found)

It would be nice if anyone can help me.

edit:

I changed the suggestion from "Logic Wreck" a little bit (because it was not possible to change the index.php to another):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

and it works great :).

Comment: append a [last|L](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) flag, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```